# How can I no-wrap a column so that when I hover over the first column the last column then displays half out of the container?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, bootstrap-4

How can I no-wrap a column so that when I hover over the first column the last column then displays half out of the container?

I tried to make it so that when I hover on the `box-hover` class column it sets the `25%` to `flex: 0 0 50%;` in my column. This is working fine but last the column wraps.

I want it so that when I hover `box-hover` then the last column displays out of the container, and the last column is half shown and half hidden.

I have attached an image of what I am trying to accomplish. Thanks in advance.

I want:

[image]

My code:

```css
.main-wraper {
  padding: 150px 0;
  background-color: #7070702b;
}
.box {
  height: 345px;
  background-color: #36495E;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
span {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 90px;
  width: 100%;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #5195CE;
 }
 .box-hover {
  transition: ease-in-out 0.5s;
}
.box-hover:hover {
  -ms-flex: 0 0 50%;
  flex: 0 0 50%;
  max-width: 50%;
}
 .box-hover span {
  background-color: #89c440;
 }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<section class="main-wraper">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3 box-hover">
        <div class="box position-relative">
          <span class="d-flex flex-column justify-content-center">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy</span>
        </div>
      </div>
     <div class="col-md-3">
       <div class="box position-relative">
         <span class="d-flex flex-column justify-content-center">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy</span>
       </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-3">
       <div class="box position-relative">
         <span class="d-flex flex-column justify-content-center">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy</span>
       </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-3">
       <div class="box position-relative">
         <span class="d-flex flex-column justify-content-center">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy</span>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can use **`flex-nowrap` for `row`** and when hover than decrese siblings **div width** and add **overflow:hidden to parent**

```css
.main-wraper {
  padding: 150px 0;
  background-color: #7070702b;
}
.container.overhidden{
  overflow:hidden;
  padding:0px 55px;
  max-width:1280px;
}
.box {
  height: 345px;
  background-color: #36495E;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
span {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 90px;
  width: 100%;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #5195CE;
 }
 .box-hover {
  transition: ease-in-out 0.5s;
}
.box-hover:hover {
  -ms-flex: 0 0 50%;
  flex: 0 0 50%;
  max-width: 50%;
}
 .box-hover span {
  background-color: #89c440;
 }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<section class="main-wraper">
  <div class="container overhidden">
    <div class="row flex-nowrap">
      <div class="col-md-3 box-hover">
        <div class="box position-relative">
          <span class="d-flex flex-column justify-content-center">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy</span>
        </div>
      </div>
     <div class="col-md-3">
       <div class="box position-relative">
         <span class="d-flex flex-column justify-content-center">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy</span>
       </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-3">
       <div class="box position-relative">
         <span class="d-flex flex-column justify-content-center">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy</span>
       </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-3">
       <div class="box position-relative">
         <span class="d-flex flex-column justify-content-center">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy</span>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
</section>
```

Comment: you need to change width of container and add padding to it so remaining space in container use for hover, check it

Answer (score 1):

You can probably consider negative margin for that last column on hover and hide the overflow:

```css
.container {
  overflow:hidden;
}
 
.main-wraper {
  padding: 150px 0;
  background-color: #7070702b;
}
.box {
  height: 345px;
  background-color: #36495E;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
span {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 90px;
  width: 100%;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #5195CE;
 }
 .box-hover {
  transition: ease-in-out 0.5s;
}
.box-hover:hover {
  -ms-flex: 0 0 50%;
  flex: 0 0 50%;
  max-width: 50%;
}
 .box-hover span {
  background-color: #89c440;
 }
 /*addedd*/
 .col-md-3:last-child  {
  transition: margin 0s 0.5s; /*remove margin when the hover ends*/
}
 .box-hover:hover ~.col-md-3:last-child {
   margin-right:-30%;
  transition: margin 0s; /*add margin immediately on hover*/
 }
 /**/
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<section class="main-wraper">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3 box-hover">
        <div class="box position-relative">
          <span class="d-flex flex-column justify-content-center">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy</span>
        </div>
      </div>
     <div class="col-md-3">
       <div class="box position-relative">
         <span class="d-flex flex-column justify-content-center">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy</span>
       </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-3">
       <div class="box position-relative">
         <span class="d-flex flex-column justify-content-center">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy</span>
       </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-3">
       <div class="box position-relative">
         <span class="d-flex flex-column justify-content-center">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy</span>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
</section>
```

Another idea is to consider negative margin inside and decrease the width of the element to hide half of it:

```css
.main-wraper {
  padding: 150px 0;
  background-color: #7070702b;
}
.box {
  height: 345px;
  background-color: #36495E;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  margin-right:0;
}
span {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 90px;
  width: 100%;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #5195CE;
 }
 .box-hover {
  transition: ease-in-out 0.5s;
}
.box-hover:hover {
  -ms-flex: 0 0 50%;
  flex: 0 0 50%;
  max-width: 50%;
}
 .box-hover span {
  background-color: #89c440;
 }
 /*addedd*/
 .col-md-3:last-child,
 .col-md-3:last-child .box{
  transition: 0s 0.5s;
}
 .box-hover:hover ~.col-md-3:last-child {
   margin-right:-30%;
   flex-basis:12.5%!important;
   overflow:hidden;
  transition: 0s; 
 }
 .box-hover:hover ~.col-md-3:last-child .box {
   margin-right:-100%;
   transition: 0s;
 }
 /**/
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<section class="main-wraper">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3 box-hover">
        <div class="box position-relative">
          <span class="d-flex flex-column justify-content-center">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy</span>
        </div>
      </div>
     <div class="col-md-3">
       <div class="box position-relative">
         <span class="d-flex flex-column justify-content-center">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy</span>
       </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-3">
       <div class="box position-relative">
         <span class="d-flex flex-column justify-content-center">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy</span>
       </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-3">
       <div class="box position-relative">
         <span class="d-flex flex-column justify-content-center">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy</span>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
</section>
```

Comment: How to last column half hide any solution?

Answer (score 1):

Default "row" class have flex-wrap:wrap just use "flex-nowrap" class with row and it will not wrap your boxes to next line. Hope it helps

```css
.main-wraper {
  padding: 150px 0;
  background-color: #7070702b;
}
.box {
  height: 345px;
  background-color: #36495E;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
span {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 90px;
  width: 100%;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #5195CE;
 }
 .box-hover {
  transition: ease-in-out 0.5s;
}
.box-hover:hover {
  -ms-flex: 0 0 50%;
  flex: 0 0 50%;
  max-width: 50%;
}
 .box-hover span {
  background-color: #89c440;
 }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<section class="main-wraper">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row flex-md-nowrap">
      <div class="col-md-3 box-hover">
        <div class="box position-relative">
          <span class="d-flex flex-column justify-content-center">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy</span>
        </div>
      </div>
     <div class="col-md-3">
       <div class="box position-relative">
         <span class="d-flex flex-column justify-content-center">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy</span>
       </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-3">
       <div class="box position-relative">
         <span class="d-flex flex-column justify-content-center">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy</span>
       </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-3">
       <div class="box position-relative">
         <span class="d-flex flex-column justify-content-center">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy</span>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
</section>
```